# Sitefinity - References in project not found when under source control

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, sitefinity

Hi folks I have a couple of questions.

We installed the trial version of Sitefinity. I`ve created a project on my machine and everything seems to be running well. I started developing and getting a sense of the CMS. I uploaded the project on TFS and my colleague got the sources, but when he builds the solution its seems of all the refrences are missing and does not compile because it does not find the namespace  Telerik.Sitefinity.Cloud.WindowsAzure in the class AzureWebRole.cs,

1.What to do so when creating a project the corresponding side can work freely.

When he tries to create a project he gets the following exception.[image]

2. What should be done so he can create a project?

   What I find strange is that the default project is getting hosted and the solution is being build without problems but others project which are added are problematic.

**EDIT**
- The second problem was fixed when removed offline projects which were with missing references. The First question remains -> how to create a WebApp under source control so it will be alright on other workstations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sitefinty you need to checkin all DLLs in the bin, except for the sitefinitywebapp.dll